# How to enhance performance of MySQL query with for loop

Tags: javascript, sql, mysql, node.js, performance

I have node/express app and it connects to MySQL to fetch data.

I have a simple query like below

```js
const queries = [];
for (let i = 0; i < students ? .length; i++) {
  let query = `
    SELECT id, addmissionDate, standard
      FROM studentTable
      WHERE id = student[i].id 
        AND
        name = student[i].name`;
  queries.push(query);
}
```

How do I execute above list of queries ? => using **promise** with **map**.

```js
db.getConnection(async(connectionErr, connection) => {
  if (connectionErr) {
    return cb(connectionErr);
  }
  const queryResults = await Promise.all(
    queries.map(async(query) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        db.query(query, [], (err, result) => { // every time each query executes against database
          if (err) {
            return resolve([]);
          } else {
            const separeteQueryResult = [];
            if (result === null) {
              result = []
            }
            return resolve(result);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
  connection.release();
  return cb(null, queryResults);
})
```

**Problem:** with this approach is as **students** (array of objects) length increases, it takes time to execute individual query (basically one after another - **NOTE** above is just an example, in real world I have complex and heavy queries) because each query will execute against database.

**Benefit:**: If one of the queries fails, I will still get result of other successfully executed queries. So I had opted this approach.

---

I know **one solution** is to use **union all** as show below,

```
let query = ""
for (let i = 0; i < students?.length; i++) {
  if(i!==0 && query!==""){
    query = query + " union all"
  }
  query = query + `SELECT id, addmissionDate, standard
      FROM studentTable
      WHERE id = student[i].id 
        AND
        name = student[i].name`;
  }
  db.getConnection(async (connectionErr, connection) => {
    if (connectionErr) {
      return cb(connectionErr);
    }
    db.query(query, [], (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        cb(err)
      } else {
        cb(result)
      }
      connection.release();
      return cb(null, queryResults);
    })
```

**Problem:** if one if union all queries fails, then entire query fails

**Benefit:** is it is faster in execution than previous approach

---

I guess the best solution could be writing a stored procedure(SP) but I don't know how SP works with list of objects/array.

If someone can help me write better and performant approach....

Comment: Wouldnt a transaction work in your favor? Bundle your queries and send them as one action to the server?

Comment: I don't have much knowledge on database n queries. I know above both approaches are not good but I had to live with it. Now I want to improve it.

Comment: If `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table, there is no need to test for `name`, too.  Or is there?

Answer (score 0):

Try using batch processing instead of executing individual queries for each student and combine them into a single query using the `IN` operator. This should improve performance.

```
const studentIds = students.map(student => student.id).join(',');

const query = `
  SELECT 
    id,
    admissionDate,
    standard
  FROM
    studentTable
  WHERE 
    id IN (${studentIds})
`;

db.getConnection(async (connectionErr, connection) => {
  if (connectionErr) {
    return cb(connectionErr);
  }

  db.query(query, [], (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      connection.release();
      return cb(err);
    } else {
      connection.release();
      return cb(null, result);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer but in reality the query is complex. The above query is just for explanation purpose. I completely agree with your approach but I just updated my query. Basically I have complex query and many  `AND clause`.

Comment: Post your full query

Comment: I already updated with 1 AND clause. Again telling, query is for explanation only. I need better approach.